# React.js - Can't access an element's value in an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I feel like a lousy developper coming to you with that question but I'm going in circles.

I'm using React/JS and here's the problem :

The code imports an **array of objects** from my personnal API via ajax *(axios)*.
My state expect an array : `const [ films, setFilms ] = useState([]);` and receives one.

Indeed, the **response.result** from my API is an **array of 20 movie objects** :

[image]

I just want to pass it as props to another component in which I'm gonna use **one of the object stored** in the array to use and display its values but I've been unable to do so...so far.

Now, in React, when I test to call one movie like this :
`console.log("films", films);` => **WORKS** *(shows screen capture above)*,
`console.log("film", films[0]);` => **WORKS** *(shows first element, an object)*,

But if I try to enter it *(any properties)* :
`console.log("film", films[0].id);` OR `console.log("film", films[0]["id"]);`
=> **FAILS : TypeError: films[0] is undefined** !

I know I'm missing something. I receive an array of object, **can** enter an element but **can't** read its properties...

I feel lost... Help ? :)
Thank you

Comment: Are you using redux or simple react js?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can add your code snippet, where you're accessing array's of object.

Comment: Can you try console.log("film_type", typeof(films[0])) and check if the response "object "?

Comment: What it shows when `console.log(Object.keys(films[0]));`

Comment: Hi, simple React.js. I'm sure tons of developpers must have come across this scenario but I didn't found an answer.

Comment: From the above screenshot, whatever you are trying is correct :) , either you are trying to get value of films[0] out of the react this context, if you can share full class where you are trying to do this.

Comment: @Jawadulhassan I don't have this kind of snippet yet because I can't even access  the values and show them in the console.

Comment: @Mamun It is an object : ```film_type object```

Comment: @GonZo, it should give you all the available keys, it seems there is no key named `id`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your `console.log("films", films);` method is called a couple of times even films are not loaded yet. When you try to log films it will first log null or an empty array, but then it will show the correct list. On the other hand, when you have `console.log("film", films[0].id);`, your app will crash because it was called while films array is null or empty.

So make sure that your film array length is greater than 0 before logging.

Comment: Hi, yeah I was suspecting it would be around that kind of problem. thank you

Comment: @GonZo if it is the correct answer, I would appreciate a checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

try using the **&&** operator like this :

```
console.log("film", films[0] && films[0].id);
```

Comment: It does work for the ```console.logs```.. I'm flabergasted ! lol   
Could you quickly explain it to me ? I guess it's a new ES6 syntax / trick ? Anyway thank you

Comment: using the && operator make let's say when **films[0]** is available(true) take the id from that array  you can use it on any function try it and come back to me I hope i explained properly I would appreciate a checkmark

Comment: yes you did, thank you. For the checkmark, I'm new but I can see I can only give one. I already did for the answer above, sorry.

Comment: I hope i helped no problem have a nice day